# strings with uppercase and lower case transformation

Tags: c++, string

The following code ensures that we are accepting a string,it just prints the uppercase letter in the string by converting it to lowercase. How does the code ensure this ? The string may be as follows. The input string r can be any of these:

```
Kira
hates
is
he
L

for(size_t j = 0; j < r.size(); j++)
    if(r[j] <= 'Z')
        r[j] = (char) (r[j] + 'a' - 'A');
```

Comment: the question has been edited so don't down vote it now. Instead answer.

Comment: @PaulRooney yes the code works but my understanding on its working is not great or clear

Comment: Look at the acii codes for the characters `a-z` and `A-Z`. If you are on windows use the character map application. For which characters is `if(r[j] <= 'Z')` true? And what is the value of `'a' - 'A'` in numeric terms. Is it the same value for any matching lowercase and uppercase letter? e.g. `'z' - 'Z'`?

Comment: @PaulRooney it just prints the uppercase letter of string by converting it lowercase but how does this code ensure this ?

Comment: It ensures this by taking advantage of how uppercase and lowercase character are laid out in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). If you examine the ASCII codes for uppercase and lowercase characters you should be able to figure it out, and understand it, all by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all `if(r[j] <= 'Z')` checks if the character value is less than `'z'` or 90 in decimal. If you look at the ascii table you'll know that the letters A to Z are decimal 65 to 90. So any value between this is a capital letter.

So in the example of `Kira` when it checks `K` which has a value of 75. `if(75 <= 90)` which will evaluate to true.

The next step is to change the letter to lowercase. So the on the ascii table lowercase a and uppercase A are 32 apart or by using `'a' - 'A'` which evaluates to 32. So because the Uppercase appears first on the table you want to add 32 to the uppercase letter to get the lowercase.
So the lower case is from 97 to 122. So when K which is 75 + 32 = 107. Which when you look on the acii table in decimal its `k`.